# I am not able to display the pages/components in React using BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

Here is my code for the App.js and Home.js
I want to display Home.js on the browser.

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

The index file is as follows
index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

So I want to display it on browser but I am unable

Comment: What version of react router are you using? If you don't know it should say in your package.json file. If you are using V6 then this is incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
     </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Its working thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `Home` component be a child instead of being prop? I mean:

```
<Route>
    <Home/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Please dont question in answer. If there is question the it should me mentioned in comment.